# SQLRPGLE source size limit

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Is there a limit to what the SQL pre-compiler can handle for an SQLRPGLE source object?

I have had some problems compiling a 25,000 line program and a line limit is the only thing that would explain the errors I'm getting

Comment: The 7.1 version of the precompiler is much more relaxed about limits than earlier versions were.  That being said, I do not recall a documented line count limit.

Answer (score 6):

A few thoughts ...

1. What error are you getting when compiling?  The idea that a 25k line program might cause the SQL pre-compile a problem is not outside the realm of possibility ... consider that the pre-compiler creates a new source member (in QTEMP) that gets passed through the normal compile, and this new source member is larger than the original.  WAY back when I worked at SSA, we had <strike>problems</strike> (freudian slip) *programs* that were written in AS/SET that caused the compiler to choke on the size of the source members it generated.  I don't remember the limitations though.
2. A 25k line program is pretty damn huge ... might not be a bad idea to take a hard look at the program and see if it could be broken up into logical modules that are bound together into a program object.

Comment: Sometimes the error messages may not always be clear as to indicating what the actual problem is.  Please tell us what the messages are.

Comment: Agree with the fact that 25K is pretty large, and should probably be broken up.

Answer (score 0):

as @WarrenT said, tell us what the messages are.

We do have SQLRPGLE source code bigger than 25k lines and compiled just fine.
There is no limit (as i know of) if using RPG IV. The limits of 32k or so lines only if using SEU editor. If i'm not mistaken, RPG III and older do have some limits.

Use Websphere RSE (Remote System Explorer or whatever its name now) if your code is bigger than 32k.

Agree with @david and others - 25k is huge. We don't normally write huge codes, the one we have comes from 3rd party written in tools like AS/SET.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a program that got to about 40k lines. The compiler had no problem with it this size but you couldn't open it in SEU. Eclipse was ok but SEU has a limit of 32k lines due to the size of the line count in the margin.

What we had to do was create a second source member and /copy it in at the bottom. A horrible workaround but what else are you going to do with a program that size!